# JMeter JSON Path Extractor how-to

Tags: jmeter

I want to pull out href values where `id : 923` using JSON extractor for Jmeter.

I tried,

`$..entries[?(@.id == '923')].links[0].href`

But it didn't work. How should I get the values by their id?

Here's some sample data.

```
"entries":[{
    "id":"921",
    "updated":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z",
    "links":[{
      "href":"url1",
      "rel":"related-action",
      "title":"Execute related action"
     },{
      "href":"url2",
      "rel":"icon"
     }
    ]
   },{
    "id":"922",
     "updated":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z",
    "links":[{
      "href":"url3",
      "rel":"related-action",
      "title":"Execute action"
     },{
      "href":"url4",
      "rel":"icon"
     }
    ]
   },{
    "id":"923",
       "updated":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z",
    "links":[{
      "href":"url5",
      "rel":"related-action",
      "title":"Execute action"
     },{
      "href":"url6",
      "rel":"icon"
     }
    ]
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try removing quotation marks so your JSON Path Expression would look like:

   ```
   $..entries[?(@.id == 923)].links[0].href
   ```
2. Your JSON is malformed, you need to surround it with `{}` characters in order so JSON Path Extractor could work with it.
3. Try updating Extras with Libs set plugin to the latest version - 1.3.0 as for the moment.

References:

- [JSON Path Syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)
- [Parsing JSON](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)